# How can I target .Net 4.0 Beta using NAnt?

Tags: .net-4.0, nant

I want to start testing my project using the Microsoft .Net 4.0 Beta version that has already been released. I know that adding a "net-4.0" target framework to NAnt requires updating nant.exe.config file, does anyone know what are the necessary changes?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215731/building-net-4-projects-with-nant - although it's a later question it has an accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use nant to build projects targeting .NET 4.0 you'll have to modify `NAnt.exe.config` and add the net-4.0 target framework and add a `<supportedRuntime ... />` line to the `<startup>` section.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, you saved me a lot of messing around. I am using .Net 4.0.21006 and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

http://paigecsharp.blogspot.com/2009/08/nant-net-framework-40-configuration.html is a full code for .config file for NAnt.