# MSBuild failing for CruiseControl 1.6

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, nant, cruisecontrol

G'day.

We've updated to ccnet 1.6 due to our TFS server being upgraded to 2010.
Within our ccnet.config we're executing a nant (0.9) build script that contains an MSBuild exec task.

Running MSBuild at command line with the parameters as specified by the nant script works okay, but for some reason when ccnet executes the MSBuild task via the nant script it fails with the following:

External Program Failed: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe (return code was 128)

The nant exec task:

```
<property name="MSBuildPath" value="${framework.dir}\MSBuild.exe"/>
    <exec program="${MSBuildPath}">
        <arg line="${project.svds}.sln" />
        <arg value="/t:Rebuild" />
        <arg value="/p:Configuration=Release" />
        <arg value="/p:Platform=x86" />
        <arg value="/verbosity:normal" />
        <arg line="/logger:'C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll'"/>
   </exec>
```

Unfortunately no more is revealed and it's all rather cryptic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [128  There are no child processes to wait for](http://www.hiteksoftware.com/mize/Knowledge/articles/049.htm).

Set MSBuildPath as below and try...

```
<property name="MSBuildPath" value="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe" />
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215731/building-net-4-projects-with-nant) thread might help you.

**EDIT**

Possibly this can be due to the service user account. It may be running as the Local System account. Changing the service account - via Control Panel / Administrative Tools / Services may help.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should add that framework.dir points to that directory. I tried what you suggested but it didn't work